# CAML, how to get Fields which are having Unique condition

Tags: sharepoint-online, caml-query, caml, camlviewfields

I am trying to get the field info of a list and I need to also know whether the field has `Enforce unique values`: as `true`.

```
IEnumerable<List> lists = clientContext.LoadQuery( lists.Include(list =>
list.Title, list => list.Id, list => list.DefaultViewUrl, list => list.BaseType,
list => list.SchemaXml).Where( list => (list.Title == listName)));

lists = clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
List required = lists.FirstOrDefault()
```

if i go through the `required.SchemaXml` then i find the following details on the fields

```
<Field ID="{03e45e84-1992-4d42-9116-26f756012634}" RowOrdinal="0" Type="ContentTypeId" Sealed="TRUE" ReadOnly="TRUE" Hidden="TRUE" DisplayName="Content Type ID" Name="ContentTypeId" DisplaceOnUpgrade="TRUE" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="ContentTypeId" ColName="tp_ContentTypeId" FromBaseType="*TRUE" />
```

In the Details info on unique constrain is not present.

How to retrieve the unique constraint value?